# Push notifications not being received on distribute

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I had successfully implemented push notifications for the developer certificate but cannot seem to get it work for an ad hoc test with a friend. I did the same process for creating the push notification keys/certificates except now I chose "Production Push SSL Certificate" instead of "Development Push SSL Certificate". I believe that this is correct since I could not find any tutorials around that showed how to do it for production... all of them were for development.

This quick process can be found from ray wenderlich blog here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

This is my guess where things might have gone wrong because maybe there is a different way to do Production Push. I left my php code the same on my server as I had it before for Development Push (copied over the new ck.pem). Is this alright or do I need to make changes? I can post the code if someone thinks it is the code but as I said.. the php server code worked before.

Can someone please help me out? Thanks in advance!

**I CANNOT ANSWER MY QUESTION BECAUSE I DO NOT HAVE ENOUGH REP. THE CORRECT ANSWER IS HERE**

for my development I had:

```
gateway.push.apple.com:2195
```

but for production it needs to be:

```
gateway.apple.com:2195
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edited]

You can also try to check your token are correctly set, your devices are allowed to receive notifications.

If you have made many tests, you may also have been temporarily banned from APNS server, you mustn't make too many calls to the APNS server in a small time range.

Please also note that there may be some delays from the time you send the notification to the APNS server, and the time the APNS server sends it to your device.

LAst bu not least, make sure your devices have a correct Internet / SSL free access some proxies or firewalls may block notifications

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply. I did not know ad hoc did not work for the production certificate... I feel like this is why it is not working since I did pretty much everything correct I think. Are you sure about this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the devices token dynamically? Because when the app is in ad-hoc distribution it is generating a different device token for push notifications form when it is in debug (a.k.a developer) mode

Comment: Yes I noticed that they were different. I send the token to one of my databases and then the database sends it through the php script as it had before. I even tried directly sending the new token (the production one) without going through the database.. no luck. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Is it the same process for creating production vs development except the fact you download the production certificate and use that instead?